# Generate arbitrary row of Hadamard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an order $n$, is there an algorithm which generates the $i$th row of an order-$n$ Hadamard matrix?

Comment: Why do you think that there exists a **unique** order-$n$ [Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) matrix?

Comment: @Somos Good point, edited.